LeetCode 121 problem: Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock
You are given an array prices where prices[i] is the price of a given stock on the ith day.
You want to maximize your profit by choosing a single day to buy one stock and choosing a different day in the future to sell that stock.
Return the maximum profit you can achieve from this transaction. If you cannot achieve any profit, return 0.
Example:
Input: prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
Output: 5
Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.
Note that buying on day 2 and selling on day 1 is not allowed because you must buy before you sell.
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    the tests
    tempProfit = 0
    for z in range(0, len(prices)+1):
        ####if(prices[z] < prices[z+1]):###
            for x in range(z, len(prices)):
                if(prices[x] - prices[z] > tempProfit):
                    tempProfit = prices[x]-prices[z]
    return(tempProfit)

The approach I tried is kind of "brute forcing" through all the days possible profit and saving the highest profit. it passed most of the tests but 1 - a test with a really long descending values
[10000,9999,9998,9997.......0] which happened due to long run time (because of brute forcing)
to solve this Im trying to add an if statement that will avoid going through the second for loop if the price[z] > price[z+1].
It doesnt work because it goes out of the list length for the last iteration, how can I implement my logic to this for loop without going out of the list length?

For each day, if buying the stock, the best time to sell is the day with the greatest price after the current index in the array. You can thus iterate in reverse and maintain the current largest price encountered so far for a linear solution.
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    max_price = max_diff = 0
    for price in reversed(prices):
        max_diff = max(max_diff, max_price - price)
        max_price = max(max_price, price)
    return max_diff

Similar logic may be applied for iterating forwards and maintaining the minimum.
